# jquery pass contents to $(this).text

Tags: jquery, fade

I am making a menu where on rollover, the text of the link changes (fades in). I just copied and pasted a block of code off another thread

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fade_new_text(){
        $('#what').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
            $(this).text('new text');
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
    }
    function revert(){
        $('#what').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
            $(this).text('do something');
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
    }
</script>
```

then in the body section I have the menu itself

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="what" onmouseover="fade_new_text();" onmouseout="revert();">Do something</a>
</body>
```

This works well with one link, but I need to create 7 of them and hopefully reuse this code in the future. So I need to pass both the link id and the new text to Jquery function for 6 other links, hopefully from 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseout', as it would make the most sense? I am completely new to Jquery, and would appreciate your advice on how to do that.

The test file is at http://www.voxcommunications.ca/test.html

Comment: Are you looking to pass different text to each link?

Comment: yes. All links will have different text to start and will say something different on a rollover

Comment: learn to use "Class" Selectors for repetitive use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of Bryans answer, this way prevents recurring animations when unnecessary, also adds the data-mouseout dynamically instead of rewriting the Link Text in the data-mouseout on each link.

Here is a working Example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/gYMyF/)

**HTML**

```
<a class="hoverlink" data-mouseover="Hovering here">Do something</a><br />
<a class="hoverlink" data-mouseover="Hovering again">Do something else</a><br />
<a class="hoverlink" data-mouseover="Hovering some more">Do something yet again</a><br />
<a class="hoverlink" data-mouseover="Hovering yet once more">Do something one last time</a><br />
```

**JQuery**

```
//Add the link text dynamically
$('.hoverlink').each(function() {
    $(this).data('mouseout', $(this).text());
});

//Perform hover function and prevent recurring animations
$("body").on("mouseover mouseout", '.hoverlink', function(event) {

    var text = $(this).data(event.type);

    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}, 500, function() {
        $(this).stop().text(text).animate({"opacity": 1}, 500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to JofryHS' answer, you can simplify things by taking advantage of data attributes on the anchor tags and the fact that you can bind more than one event to the same handler using jQuery.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="hoverlink" id="what" data-mouseover="Hovering over what" data-mouseout="Do something">Do something</a>

<a href="#" class="hoverlink" id="what1" data-mouseover="Hovering over what1" data-mouseout="Do something else">Do something else</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".hoverlink").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var text = elem.data(e.type); // e.type will have name of the current event

    elem.animate({"opacity": 0}, 500, function() {
        elem.text(text);
    }).animate({"opacity": 1}, 500);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dxKnr/)

Comment: +1 on the data binding, and even more on getting rid of the onmouseover, onmouseout attributes

Comment: whoa, this is all new to me! Is this going to work in browsers that don't support HTML5?

Comment: @Bryan I worked off your answer to prevent the animations from recurring when unnecessary, also simplifying the links with dynamically adding the data-mouseout. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @Natalia, I believe it will still work. Non HTML5 browsers should still happily render the attributes in the markup even though they don't understand them. And then jQuery does the rest.

Comment: @VIDesignz, I definitely think calling `stop()` on the animations and simplifying the markup even further by setting the mouseout text data using code as your answer and @Beetroot-Beetroot's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13638717/51242) do is an excellent improvement. In fact, I think @Natalia may wish to reconsider selecting one of them as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

In general a menu of this type will be a styled unordered list (ul) element, something like this.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-mouseover="Text A">Do 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-mouseover="Text B">Do 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-mouseover="Text C">Do 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-mouseover="Text D">Do 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

To keep the markup as simple as possible, we only encode the alternative (mouseover) text.

The first time each link is visited, jQuery ensures a record of the original text is kept.

```
$("#menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', "a", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop(true).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function() {
        if(!$this.data('mouseout')) {
            $this.data('mouseout', $this.text());
        }
        $this.text($this.data(e.type));
    }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f8Xh8/)

Answer (score 1):

to reuse your functions rewrite your function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fade_new_text(id, txt){
$('#'+id).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
    $(this).text(txt);
}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
}
function revert(id, txt){
$('#'+id).animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
    $(this).text(txt);
}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
 }
</script>
```

Then in your body section use something like the one below

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="what" onmouseover="fade_new_text('what','Natalia');" onmouseout="revert('what','Natalia1');">Do something
</a>

<a href="#" id="what1" onmouseover="fade_new_text('what1','Natalia1');" onmouseout="revert('what1','Natalia2');">Do something
</a>

....so on...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this:

```
function fade_new_text(text){
$('#what').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
    $(this).text(text);
}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
}
function revert(text){
$('#what').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
    $(this).text(text);
}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
 }

$(".coolLink").hover(
  function() {

    fade_new_text($(this).attr("data-text"));
  },
  function() {
    revert($(this).attr("data-original"));
  }
);
```

And tiny bit modification on your HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="what" class="coolLink" data-original="Do something" data-text="New Text">Do something
```

This will work if the text is basically switching back and forth between two text. Now for other links just use the same `class="coolLink"` with `data-original` and `data-text` and you're good to go.

Comment: In fact you only need one function since they are doing the same thing, but I'll leave it to OP should he/she decide to follow this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going the route of using a data attribute to add behaviors to your HTML would be the way I would go, you could do it with something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-fade-text="some text">link one</a>
<a href="#" data-fade-text="some text 2">link two</a>
<a href="#" data-fade-text="some text 3">link three</a>
```

-

```
$('[data-fade-text]').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.data('original-text', self.text());
});

$('[data-fade-text]').hover(
    function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
            self.text(self.data('fade-text'));
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
    },
    function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function () {
            self.text(self.data('original-text'));
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500);
    }
);​
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/fY5pj/