# Change date swapping by date fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade, offset

Thaksfor all the answer you're giving !

I manage to make a date automaticly changing when I scroll on specific "post".
you can see the result here :
http://goo.gl/Qm8mj6

scroll down until the bottom.. you will see the date changing..

But I would like to fade the date to another. Actually it just changing with no fade.
I hope I'm understanble enough..?

here is the code I'm using

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
     var pos = $('#date').offset();              
     $('.post').each(function () {             
      if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {                 
          $('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());             
          $('#date2').html($(this).find('.description2').text());           
          $('#date3').html($(this).find('.description3 ').text()); //or any other way you want to get the date                 
            return; //break the loop             
             }         
         });     
      });      
  })
```

Does anyone as a clue..?
Thanks a lot..!

Comment: See this question for one way to do text fade effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638328/jquery-pass-contents-to-this-text

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I already seen that question.. But I don't know how to apply to my code..? Don't know what to change..? Do you know what to try..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you apply the solution in the linked question to your code:

```
if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
    var desc1 = $(this).find('.description').text(),
        desc2 = $(this).find('.description2').text(),
        desc3 = $(this).find('.description3').text();
    $('#date').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).stop().text(desc1).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    });
    $('#date2').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).stop().text(desc2).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    });
    $('#date3').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).stop().text(desc3).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    });
    return false; // break the loop
}
```

Note also that you need `return false` to terminate the loop.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cdYEZ/7/)

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks ! unfortunately the code doesn't work.

The date just blink in loop, and doesn't change when it reach the second post..

Doy you know why..?

Comment: Please make a fiddle and I'll play with it later.

Comment: I think the problem in your fiddle is just a typo in the CSS. `.opacit` should be `.opacity`.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, I copied the code from the question I linked to, not its answer. I've corrected it now. But I think if you just fix your CSS you'll get what you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cdYEZ/8/

Comment: Hi, actually the opacit it's a class I named like that.. So I should the corrected code and it should work..?

Comment: The HTML has `<div class="opacity" id="date"></div>` -- it has a `y` at the end.

Comment: yep I mean, I remove the "y" cause I didn't want to use that class..I should have remove the whole css class...I will look with your code.. thanks

Comment: here is the fiddle without the uncessary class..if someone want to "play" with it ! http://jsfiddle.net/cdYEZ/9/

Answer (score 0):

Didn't manage to make the date fading when it's changing..
here is the fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/cdYEZ/9/

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
    var pos = $('#date').offset();
    $('.post').each(function () {
        if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
            $('#date').html($(this).find('.description').text());
            $('#date2').html($(this).find('.description2').text());
            $('#date3').html($(this).find('.description3 ').text()); //or any other way you want to get the date
            return; //break the loop
        }
    });
});


})
```

if someone has a clue..?

Thanks !